# In the last hundred years and the last time

Tags: expressions

Should 'the last time' always be followed by past simple and **in the last hundred years** by present perfect?

Eg., The last time I  **went** to South America, I  **visited** Brazil and Peru. I **spent** two weeks in the Amazon, **hiked** for a week near Machu Picchu, and  **flew over the Nazca Lines.**

Eg.,In the last hundred years, traveling  **has become** much easier and very comfortable.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“The last time” is a completed past, whereas “over the last 100 years” represents a period that runs right up to the present moment.

So while last year I went to the store, but this week I have gone to the store. Same thing.

Answer (score 4):

The tenses (*past simple / present perfect*) are correct in the context in which you use them above. As to your question:  "Should *the last time* always be followed by past simple and *in the last hundred years* by present perfect?", the best answer is that they usually are, but there are contexts in which they are not:

- This may be the last time that we have heard her sing. (present perfect)
- In the last hundred years of the first millenium most people lived in mud huts. (past simple)

With all due respect to my fellow answerers, I think you would be better off investing in a good pedagogial grammar, such as *Swan's Practical English Usage*, or engaging an ESL teacher. The answers to your numerous open questions, including mine, are probably more likely to lead to confusion than to enlightenment.